# How can I send custom data with the BotFramework-WebChat component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, botframework

I'm using the BotFramework-WebChat component in my React application to allow users to chat with my bot. I'd like to include custom data with the messages sent to the bot, but I'm unsure how to do this.

The custom data is an extra key-value pair. I use the `useSendMessage` hook from the **BotFramework-WebChat component**. Is there a way or a hook from which I can programmatically send the custom data back to the bot?

So far I have tried sending the custom data via the **BotFramework-WebChat component** `rest` API but that creates problems and is unsuitable for my use case.